# Spring Boot Batch always restart the failed job even with new job parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a simple Spring Batch job configured in Spring Boot. It is the same as [Creating a Batch Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) in the Getting Starte guide. I am using SQLServer for persistence of the Spring batch meta-data and business data.

I execute the job with command line parameter `fileName=error.csv` and the job fails with an error as intended. I then execute the job with command line parameter `fileName=working.csv` and the previous failed job is executed again. The different parameter is ignored. The only way to get a job with a different parameter to run is to make sure the failed job is fixed and ran successfully.

This worked perfectly in spring-boot-starter version 1.5.9 using Spring batch version 3.0.8 where I could run a new job with different parameters while the failed job is still not fixed. The problem occurs when I upgraded to spring-boot-starter version 2.0.1 using Spring batch version 4.0.1.

Is it possible to start a new job with different parameters while there is a job with a failed status in the database?

**Edit:**

I traced this back to Spring boot.
In version 2.0.0.M5 it worked as expected.
In version 2.0.0.M6 the issue started for the first time.

Version 2.0.0.M5 used the getNextJobParameters method in the JobLauncherCommandLineRunner class.
This method gets the previous job's job parameters and the add the current job's parameters to the map.
This means if the parameter values are the same, the current job's parameters are used.

Version 2.0.0.M6 changed JobLauncherCommandLineRunner to use the getNextJobParameters method in the JobParametersBuilder class.
This method always uses the previous job's job parameters.

Now, the question is: Which one of these are the correct design and how do you achieve the same result as it was in version 2.0.0.M5?

I also opened a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2711) to clarify this issue.

Comment: I've commented on the Jira issue as well, but can you please provide the actual command you're using to execute the job?  The code change you're referring to just moved a block of code from one place to another, but the code itself should have been unchanged.

Comment: I am using the following commands to start the job:
First job that causes the intended error: `java -jar myjar.jar parm=0 fileName=error.csv`

Second job that restart the first job instead of starting a new job instance: `java -jar myjar.jar parm=1 fileName=new.csv`

The code was moved from one place to another, but it also changed. I provided more information in the JIRA.